# I can't switch to | cursor in insert mode

Tags: vimrc, neovim, insert-mode, cursor

I want to change cursors to a `|` character in insert mode, and then back to a block in normal mode. I am using urxvt as my terminal, and neovim.

To switch cursors in my terminal, I run the following to get a blinking I-beam

```
echo -e "\033[5 q"
```

and then to go to a solid block:

```
echo e "\033[1 q"
```

I tried this in my `vimrc`:

```
let &t_SI = "\033[1 q"
let &t_SR = "\033[5 q"
let &t_EI = "\033[5 q"
```

but it didn't work. Nothing different from normal happens when I enter and exit insert mode.

I also tried this in my `vimrc`:

```
if has("autocmd")
  au InsertEnter * silent execute "!print -n -- '\033[1 q'"
  au InsertLeave * silent execute "!print -n -- '\033[3 q'"
  au VimLeave * silent execute "!print -n -- '\033[5 q'"
endif
```

When I enter insert mode with this, the editor shifts up one line, and the status bar is shown twice at the bottom. When I exit insert mode, I see the text `[3 q` below the statusbar. Any ideas? Thanks

Some links that I tried:

https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=177281
https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=155802

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Neovim does not use `vimrc` it uses `$XDG_CONFIG_PATH/nvim/init.vim`.  Yet, there is more to it.  In Vim you should use `\<esc>` to represent the escape key.  I can change the cursor on Arch Linux on `urxvt` with the following in my `vimrc`:

```
let &t_SI = "\<esc>[5 q"
let &t_SR = "\<esc>[5 q"
let &t_EI = "\<esc>[2 q"
```

I also tried the `autocmd` technique and it works.  Instead of the previous three lines I do:

```
au InsertEnter * silent execute "!echo -en \<esc>[5 q"
au InsertLeave * silent execute "!echo -en \<esc>[2 q"
```

And the cursor changes to a bar (`|`) in insert mode.  In `urxvt`:

- `1` is the blinky block cursor
- `2` is the default (non-blinky) block cursor
- `3` is blinky underscore
- `4` fixed underscore
- `5` pipe bar (blinking)
- `6` fixed pipe bar

---

In `neovim` things work differently.  Although `:help termcap-cursor-shape` is the same as in Vim it appears to ignore `t_SI`, `t_SR` and `t_EI`.  As Caleb Eby found out the `NVIM_TUI_ENABLE_CURSOR_SHAPE` variable controls `neovim`'s cursor shape instead.

You can therefore add:

```
let $NVIM_TUI_ENABLE_CURSOR_SHAPE = 1
```

To your `~/.config/nvim/init.vim` and the cursor will work as if the termcap variables were set as:

```
let &t_SI = "\<esc>[5 q"
let &t_SR = "\<esc>[3 q"
let &t_EI = "\<esc>[2 q"
```

(But you cannot change the values, as far as I meddled with this)

Reference:

- [:h termcap-cursor-shape](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/term.html#termcap-cursor-shape)
- [Changing cursor in Vim in iTerm](https://hamberg.no/erlend/posts/2014-03-09-change-vim-cursor-in-iterm.html)

Comment: I have my vimrc symlinked.

Comment: I got this to work in neovim by setting the environment variable NVIM_TUI_ENABLE_CURSOR_SHAPE to 1.

Comment: from https://hamberg.no/erlend/posts/2014-03-09-change-vim-cursor-in-iterm.html

Comment: @CalebEby - Wow, that's some pretty inconsistency in neovim.  But yeah it appers to work well that way.  I tested it a little and expanded the answer.